# if I create a category in Wordpress , it automatically creates a children subcategory . Can I get a perfect solution?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a category in wordpress. and it gives me a new category with auto created subcategory. Example- If I create a category named "cricket", it is created with a new "featured" subcategory which is auto created. then when I created another category named "football". It is also created with a new subcategory automatically.

please find me a solution.

Comment: You have these cool hooks - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/create_taxonomy/ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_taxonomy/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_term/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create terms to specific taxonomy here are 2 of them.

First hook is better used when we target multiple taxonomies

```
function create_autogen_terms($term_id,$tt_id,$taxonomy,$args) {
    $tax = 'my taxonomy'; // Which taxonomy we want to target e.g. category, post_tag etc.

    //If we create a term in the taxonomy we check if its name is Cricket
    if($taxonomy === $tax && $args['name'] === 'Cricket' ):
        wp_insert_term(
            'Featured',
            $tax,
            array(
                'slug' => 'featured',
                'parent'=> $term_id
            )
        );
    endif;
}
add_action('create_term','create_autogen_terms',10,4);
```

This hook is better used when we target specific taxonomy only

```
function create_autogen_terms_by_taxonmy($term_id,$tt_id,$args) {

    //If we create a term in the taxonomy we check if its name is Cricket
    if($args['name'] === 'Cricket' ):
        wp_insert_term(
            'Featured',
            $tax,
            array(
                'slug' => 'featured',
                'parent'=> $term_id
            )
        );
    endif;
}
//Replace {$taxonomy} with taxonomy we want to target e.g. category, post_tag etc.
add_action('create_{$taxonomy}','create_autogen_terms',10,3);
```